# Configuring Okta IDP with keycloak

Tags: keycloak, okta, keycloak-services, okta-api

Recently I started using Keycloak, My requirement is that I want to configure Okta as an IDP. I was able to do that but the problem is each IDP will have an alias which should be unique for that realm in Keycloak. Also what I noticed was the redirect url looked something like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/<realm-name>/broker/<idp-alias-name>/endpoint
```

The problem I have with this is that I have already integrated my application with Okta and it's in their marketplace as well. Also, we have to mention the redirect URIs ( where Okta should reply to ) in the ISV portal.

When my clients integrate my app from the Okta marketplace they will get a client-id and a client-secret. Since I am using Keycloak I can store them in the provider table, but according to Keycloak's redirect URL, it will be different for different integrations because of which I have to update the ISV form on each new integration. I might be missing something OR can I have a single redirect URL for multiple integrations?
Can anyone help me with this?

For reference, the ISV form looks like this,

[image: ISV-Form]

The Keycloak URL looks like this,

[image: Keycloak_GUI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the OIN form fully, in Okta OIN form they have a feature that is "varying redirect-url per tenant". It's visible in the image posted above.

If I enable that then basically I can have any amount of redirect URI's.